# What does this kind of keyword use do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby, and learning Ruby on Rails.

I saw this code:

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
  layout false

  def index
  end
end
```

What does `layout false` mean?

I've seen the `include` keyword, but I've never seen `layout` before. Is a Rails specific keyword?

What exactly does the 'keyword space keyword' form mean in Ruby, and is there a language specification? And can I create my own 'keywords'?

Comment: `layout` is not a keyword.

Comment: `layout false` means that only the view is rendered without the layout... In this case, there only `index.html.erb` without headers, footers, assets etc...

Comment: `layout false` means that `application.html.*`(used by default) from `app/views/layouts` will not be rendered, you will render only template `index.html.*`, etc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layout` isn't a keyword. `layout false` is the same as `layout(false)`. The parentheses are optional for method calls in Ruby.

See [the `layout` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts/ClassMethods.html#method-i-layout) for details of the `layout()` method in Rails.

Comment: So basically, `layout false` is `layout` method call directly on `DemoController` class object (which is implicit message receiver in this context).

Comment: Yes, exactly - it's a class method.

Comment: No, it's not. I know it is tempting to explain such concepts using analogies from other languages, but ultimately, it is confusing and not helpful for newbies. An experienced Rubyist may use the term "class method" and know fully well that there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby, and saying "class method" is really just short hand for "regular old instance method of the singleton class of an object which just so happens to be an instance of the `Class` class", but for newbies, talking about "class methods" when they don't actually exist, is utterly confusing.

Comment: Instead of using "here" for anchor text, use something more meaningful that informs the reader where "here" will take them.

Comment: Here's a great example of someone getting confused because he thinks there are class methods in Ruby, when in fact there are none: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27614328/2988

Comment: @Marek Lipka 
I'm confusing now… What the "implicit message receiver" means? Is that just kind of a constructor function which is called when instantiation? Could you suggest me some keywords for research? I want to get more detailed informations about it. Thanks!

Comment: @user3577446 "implicit message receiver" is the object that receives method call without explicitly specified receiver in given context. This object is pointed with `self` word. Since in this context, `self` points to `DemoController` class, this class (remember, in Ruby class is also an object) receives `layout` call. You could read more about `self` in Ruby.

Comment: @Marek Lipka Thanks! Is that means the `layout false`  in this context equivalent for `DemoController.layout(false)`? If it is, I'm wondering when it is called? Because I've never seen method calling inside a Class-Definition in other language before. It's weird...

Answer (score 3):

[`layout false`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) means that render will be without any layouts.

Answer (score 0):

The view in ruby on rails applications takes the layout defined in layouts/application.html.erb by default. In case you want to use any different layout for specific views, you can change the layout parameter. 
Here the

> views under Demo controller will not use the default layout

. You can also use layout parameters while rendering templates/view files. These are pre-defined keywords and in case you are looking for own set of keywords. You have to override these, but it's not a best practice considering ruby's "convention over configuration". For details can check [Rails layout guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)