# How is a call to instance_methods dispatched in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

`instance_methods` is defined as a public instance method within the `Module` class. Why and how are we then able to call `Object.instance_methods`, which is the syntax for class method invocation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I invoke an instance method on a Ruby module without including it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322470/can-i-invoke-an-instance-method-on-a-ruby-module-without-including-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`instance_methods`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) is a instance method on `Module`, that method can be called on any instance of the `Module` class or it's subclasses.

As it turns out, `Object` *is* an instance of the `Class` class:

```
Object.instance_of? Class
#=> true
```

And, `Class` is a subclass of `Module`:

```
Class < Module
#=> true
```

Here's a helpful chart illustrating the class hierarchy of the various objects in Ruby. Notice how `Module` is listed as a superclass of `Class`, which all Classes in Ruby are instances of:

[image: Ruby class hierarchy]

[View full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1taqB.png)

Comment: Where is this graph coming from, was it ploted specifficaly for this answer?

Comment: @psychoslave I don't remember now, but it seems to be from this guy on the Ruby forums? https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/the-ruby-object-model/237824 Not sure why I didn't cite the source all those years ago, but there it is.

Comment: Thank you @ajedi32. Too bad the working version on giffy seems now unavailable. Having a version we could update if required would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a class method in this case, but in Ruby, Object is just an instance of Class, which has Module as a super class. So what looks like a class method here is actually an instance method invoke on instance Object of class Class.

```
Object.instance_of? Class # => true
Object.is_a? Module #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as the "syntax of class method invocation". There is also no such thing as a "class method".

This is just method invocation like any other method invocation. You are calling the method `instance_methods` on the object referenced by the constant `Object`. That object is the `Object` class, which is an instance of the `Class` class. `Class` is a subclass of `Module`, and so the `Object` class is an (indirect) instance of the `Module` class which defines the `instance_methods` method.

Comment: How can you state that there is no such thing as a class method. There are class and instance methods for almost all classes in ruby. Also there is literally a Class named Method ;)

Comment: @engineersmnky: No, there are no class methods. What we *call* "class methods" are actually just singleton methods on the object which happens to be a class. But actually, there are no singleton methods either, what we *call* "singleton methods" are actually just regular old instance methods of the singleton class. So, "class methods" are actually just regular old instance methods of the singleton class of an object which just happens to be a class.

Comment: In that event shouldn't ::singleton_methods return the same as say ::methods? How does BasicObject fall into this. I am not trying to be argumentative I just find this interesting.